# write a file after create some random strings

Tags: python

```
import random
class simulate_DNA:
    def create_DNA(length):
        sequence = ""
        for i in range(length):
            sequence = sequence + random.choice("ATGC")
        return print(sequence)
def main():
    length = 10
    output_file = input("Enter output file path and name: ")
    output_file = open(output_file, "w")
    for i in range(10):
        # simulate_DNA.create_DNA(length)
        output_file.write(simulate_DNA.create_DNA(length))
        output_file.readline()
    output_file.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got this error after running the code above: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
Would anyone please tell me how to fix this error? Thank you so much!

Comment: Returning print from the create_DNA function returns None.

Comment: `return sequence`

Comment: Additionally, in the main function, readline() cannot be used if output_file is opened for writing. If you want to read the file change 'w' to 'w+' in open()

Comment: Would you please tell me why return print(sequence) doesn't print a random string?

Answer (score 1):

The print function returns None, and you're trying to return the result of the print function => So it's None

Replace this:
`return print(sequence)`
By:
`return sequence`

Comment: Would you please tell me why return print(sequence) doesn't print a random string?

Comment: The `print(sequence)` does print the random string. But it returns `None` instead of the random string you expected. So this lead to the error at this line `output_file.write(simulate_DNA.create_DNA(length))` because you're trying to do `output_file.write(None)`. This is illegal as file writer only allows the string and integer but None.

Comment: So why does simulate_DNA.create_DNA(length) create None in this case?

Comment: Because the function `create_DNA` returns `print(...)` which is none.